# python lsb_release not working in debian 9

Tags: debian, python

I cannot get lsb_release module to work in python 2.7 or 3 on debian 9. I haven't tried on debian 8 yet but I need it to work on both.

Here's what I tried:

```
import lsb_release
print(lsb_release.get_lsb_information())
```

it returned `{}` I don't get an import error, I don't know why it doesn't work. Also, when running a script via sudo with `user = os.environ['SUDO_USER']` I get a key error, SUDO_USER doesn't exist? What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don’t ask multiple questions in one.

Regarding your first question, you should use `get_distro_information()` instead. `get_lsb_information()` is used internally to load overrides from `/etc/lsb-release`; `get_distro_information()` uses that, along with other methods in the class, to provide the appropriate information.

Regarding your second question, if `SUDO_USER` really isn’t present in the environment exported by `sudo` (run `sudo env` to check), that probably means that your `sudoers` configuration deletes the variable from the environment.